# A way of handling validation in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, validation

I want to perform **validations** for **TextBoxes** in **WPF**.
Validations are like,
1) Checking Emptiness of a Control
2) validating Email Address
3) validating Mobile Number

I know How to handling all kind of validations in Asp.Net.
But Don't know in WPF.
Till now I am handling from code behind but I think that is not correct way.
I want to perform validations after Click Event just like in our Asp.Net.
Please give me your valuable suggestions.

Comment: Actually, you can use the same way as ASP .NET MVC does - data annotations. In WPF you have to use it in combination with IDataErrorInfo interface. Since this isn't only possible solution, I won't mark this as duplicate, but here's a link: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7100959/580053 , and here's another one: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22362049/580053

Comment: Start reading here: [Data Validation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347(v=vs.100).aspx#data_validation).

Comment: Thanks for your valuable suggestions now  I got it. @Clemens